# Facebook fbDidLogin gets called multiple times after [facebook authorize:permissions]

Tags: iphone, facebook, cocoa-touch

I have a problem when I try to login to facebook with my app (with facebook IOS app installed). Everything works fine, but fbDidLogin on the delegate method gets called twice.

I call this method once:

```
-(BOOL)checkForValidFBSessionAndAuthorize
{
    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"publish_stream",
                                nil];
        [facebook authorize:permissions];
        [permissions release];
    }
    return [facebook isSessionValid];
}
```

and I get redirected to the facebook app, then my app is reawaken and "- (void)fbDidLogin" gets called. 
TWICE!

My iPhone App Store ID on the facebook app is not set correctly since I just wanted to test it first, but the bundle ID is correct. Any ideeas?
Thanks!

Comment: what do you do in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation` and `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` in your appDelegate?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Sebrassi! Your guess was correct.
I was calling

```
[[FacebookService singleton].facebook handleOpenURL:url];
```

twice in

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```